# ansible win_replace module is missing

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

Are you familiar with a way to replace all the occurrences of a given string in a file on a Windows host using ansible?

The builtin replace module does not support this. Is it a new feature to develop? Is there a simple powershell command as a replacement?

Comment: could you precise what you want to do precisely in host file?

Comment: `The builtin replace module does not support this` => I don't see any note/warning in the documentation saying this module is not supported on windows targets (which most usually the case when it happens). I don't see any clear evidence of this in the [module source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/replace.py) either (it uses python re and the os module to manipulate paths...). I don't have a windows target to test. Can you be more specific about what is the exact outcome (error messages, unexpected result). And please post an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: why dont use template ?

Comment: @Frenchy Cause I don't know what is the content of the entire file.... I only need to replace some lines starting with "_meta = ". So, I thought It would be helpful to replace (by regex) all lines starting with "_meta...."
I would do that by win_lineinfile module, but It can only do so once....